# Access domain objects from controller

Tags: java, model-view-controller, javafx, javafx-8, fxml

According to [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/fxml-tutorial/why_use_fxml.htm) document FXML can be considered as "View" part of MVC. Domain objects are defined on the Java side ("Model"). I cannot find out a connection between "M" and "C" - I want to modify some domain objects (or initiate modification) from controller: "M" <- "C"

But code like this has no relations with place where I invoke FXMLLoader.load():

```
public class FXMLTableViewController {
    @FXML private TableView<Person> tableView;
    @FXML private TextField firstNameField;
    @FXML private TextField lastNameField;
    @FXML private TextField emailField;

    @FXML
    protected void addPerson(ActionEvent event) {
        ObservableList<Person> data = tableView.getItems();
        data.add(new Person(firstNameField.getText(),
            lastNameField.getText(),
            emailField.getText()
        ));

        firstNameField.setText("");
        lastNameField.setText("");
        emailField.setText("");
    }
}
```

This code completely separated from the rest code of application. What is the right way to make such connection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use the static `FXMLLoader.load(URL)` method. Instead, create an `FXMLLoader` instance. Then you can either instantiate the controller yourself and call `setController(...)`, or you can set a controller factory.

**Using `setController(...)`**

So assume you have some model class, call it `Model`. Define your controller to take a reference to it:

```
public class MyController {
    private final Model model ;

    // usual @FXML-annotated fields, etc

    public MyController(Model model) {
        this.model = model ;
    }

    public void initialize() { ... }

    // handler methods, etc...
}
```

Now, *remove the `fx:controller` attributes from your FXML file*, and instead do the following:

```
final Model model = new Model();

FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
loader.setLocation(getClass().getResource("path/to/fxml/file.fxml"));
loader.setController(new MyController(model));
Parent root = loader.<Parent>load();
```

**Using `setControllerFactory(...)`**

If you want or need to use `fx:controller` attributes (for example, if you are using `<fx:include ...>` tags in your FXML and injecting the nested controllers, which may also need access to the model), you can instead specify a controller factory, which is effectively a function that maps controller types to controller instances. The `FXMLLoader` will use this to determine how to create an object from the class name you specify in the `fx:controller` attribute.

For example:

```
final Model model = new Model();

FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("path/to/fxml/file.fxml"));
loader.setControllerFactory(new Callback<Class<?>, Object>() {
    @Override
    public Object call(Class<?> type) {
        try {
             for (Constructor<?> constructor : type.getConstructors()) {
                 if (constructor.getParameterCount()==1 && 
                         constructor.getParameterTypes()[0]==Model.class) {
                     return constructor.newInstance(model);
                  }
             }
             // no matching constructor found, just call no-arg constructor as default:
             return type.newInstance();
        } catch (Exception exc) {
            exc.printStackTrace();
            return null ; // bail...
        }
    }
});
Parent root = loader.<Parent>load();
```

Note that with this version:

1. Any FXML files included will use the same controller factory, so if their controllers have a constructor taking a single parameter of type `Model`, they'll receive a reference to the same `Model` instance
2. If you're using multiple `FXMLLoader`s in your application, you can reuse the same controller factory to pass the same `Model` instance to the loaders, so all controllers can access the same `Model` instance.

**Additional thoughts on controller factories**

The controller factory is a very powerful and flexible mechanism. For example, it would be pretty easy to define a controller factory that simply deferred to a Spring `ApplicationContext`. That way you could define interfaces for controllers, and just specify the interface name in the FXML file. Your Spring configuration file could then determine which implementation of the controller interface to use, and could of course inject models (and domain objects) into the controller for you.

**Also see**

If you're doing a lot of this, take a look at [Adam Bien's afterburner framework](http://afterburner.adam-bien.com/). Adam defines a reusable controller factory that loads controllers and checks for `@Inject` annotated fields in them, and injects a singleton instance into those fields. This gives a lot of flexibility, as you can easily add more shared resources to your controllers.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a instance of [`FXMLLoader`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/fxml/FXMLLoader.html) and use a non-static load method ([`load(java.io.InputStream inputStream)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/fxml/FXMLLoader.html#load-java.io.InputStream-) or [`load()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/fxml/FXMLLoader.html#load--)). Afterwards you can get the controller using the [`getController()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/fxml/FXMLLoader.html#getController--) method.